# Multiple quiz with checkboxes - multiple options

Tags: javascript

I have the following HTML:

```
<fieldset id="question1">
<legend>Which are fruit?</legend>
<label><INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="q1" VALUE="wrong">tomatoes<BR></label>
<label><INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="q2" VALUE="wrong">cucumber<BR></label>
<label><INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="q3" VALUE="right">apples<BR></label>
<label><INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="q4" VALUE="wrong">onion<BR></label>
<label><INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="q5" VALUE="right">bananas<BR></label>
</fieldset>
<input type="button" id="answer">
```

and JavaScript:

```
   document.getElementById("answer").onclick = validate;
    function validate() {
        var checkbox;
        var i;
        var right;
        checkboxes = document.getElementById("question1").getElementsByTagName("input");

        right = false;
        for(i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            if(checkboxes[i].value == "right" && checkboxes[i].checked == true) {
              right = true;
            }
        }

        if(right) {
            alert("You answered correctly");
        } else {
            alert("Wrong answer");
        }
    }
```

My Quiz is almost working but I only want it to be correct when all the right options are checked. At the moment when one correct option is selected it still returs as correct regardless of whether other incorrect ones were also selected.

Here is the live sample: http://jsfiddle.net/nzLmxfx7/
Thanks!

Comment: Apologies, I think I might have linked to the wrong Fiddle. Here is the correct one: http://jsfiddle.net/nzLmxfx7/2/

I must be really daft but I can't get this to work. Could someone maybe help me with the fiddle instead?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this is the wrong approach? Is there a better way perhaps? Any feedback appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, which works on my computer.

HTML:

```
<fieldset id="question1">
    <legend>Which are fruit?</legend>
    <label><INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="input" VALUE="wrong">tomatoes<BR></label>
    <label><INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="input" VALUE="wrong">cucumber<BR></label>
    <label><INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="input" VALUE="right">apples<BR></label>
    <label><INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="input" VALUE="wrong">onion<BR></label>
    <label><INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="input" VALUE="right">bananas<BR></label>
</fieldset>
<input type="button" id="answer" value="Submit">
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("answer").onclick = validate;

function validate() {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("input");
    var checkboxChecked = []; 

    for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if(checkboxes[i].checked && (checkboxes[i].value === "right")) {
            checkboxChecked.push(checkboxes[i]);
        }
    }

    if(checkboxChecked.length === 2) {
        alert("You answered correctly");
    } 
    else {
        alert("Wrong answer");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it other way. Set `right` to `true` by default and set it to `false` if either correct checkbox is not checked or wrong checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0):

You are only setting the value of flag (right) to true if user has selected a checkbox whose value is true.

You also need to set flag to false if user has selected a checkbox whose value is false.

For Ex:
If user checked apples and onions. Then your code will check apples checkbox and set the flag to true. There would be no code executing for the Onions.

I think you got my point

Add:

```
 if(checkboxes[i].value == "wrong" && checkboxes[i].checked == true) {
              right = false;
            }
```